# How to run shell scripts starting with ./ on Ubuntu and Mac without any modification?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, shell-script

Orignal code, meant for Ubuntu:

```
./rebar get-deps
./rebar compile
```

When I try:

```
sh start.sh
start.sh: line 5: ./rebar: No such file or directory
```

The fix is simple, just remove `./`

But how to make the script running both on **Ubuntu** and **Mac** without forcing user to make any changes?

---

**EDIT / UPDATE:** `rebar` is Erlang tool installed via `brew install rebar`

Here is the original `start.sh` file: https://github.com/aeternity/testnet/blob/master/start.sh

I think it's difference between Mac and Ubuntu - the script supposedly works on Ubuntu *(didn't have a chance to try)* - while on Mac I had to remove `./` *(I need to check on Ubuntu myself)*

Comment: I think you need to give us a little more info. Is `rebar` a script that is in the same directory as `start.sh`? Or is `rebar` a program available in your `$PATH`? Is the "original code" part of that `start.sh` script? What are the permissions of the respective files? (Can you post a minimal version of the `start.sh` script?) What you describe doesn't seem to be a problem caused by a difference between macOS and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

`./rebar` is adressing the file in the present workdirectory, only. Starting `rebar` forces a look-up in the directories in your `PATH` environment.

If these are the only two options you may add to your script:

```
REBAR="rebar"
[ -x ./rebar ] && REBAR="./rebar"   # check if rebar is in pwd

$REBAR get-deps
$REBAR compile 
...
```